# Setting url in a constructor function

Tags: php

If I create a constructor function within my class with the variable called `$base_url = 'mydomain'`. How could I access this via other functions as a general variable?

I have tried creating a test function with `echo $base_url` but it did not return a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it a class variable and reference it with `$this`

```
class MyClass {

    public $base_url; // change access modifier as needed

    public function __construct($base) {
        $this->base_url = $base;
    }

    public function getBaseUrl() {
        return $this->base_url;
    }

    public function url($url) {
        return $this->base_url . $url;
    }

}

$myClass = new MyClass('http://example.com/');
echo $myClass->url('register');
```

Output: `http://example.com/register`

Comment: @MartyWallace yep. Thanks. I normally use camelCase, just a habit.

Comment: What is the purpose of the getBaseUrl function when I can just call the construct?

Comment: It's just an example. constructor sets its value when the class is constructed, `getBaseUrl` just returns it (although, since its a public var now, you could just do `$classInstance->base_url` as well). But say you have another method that needs `$base_url` to do other calculations, you would access via `$this->base_url` within the class. `$this` points to the instance of the class. See my edit for a better example.

Comment: +1, this right answer, which is a really simplify class similar to one I'm using, just made me realize I was doing something inherently wrong in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to define `$base_url` outside of the function, above the constructor and then update / reference that property via `$this->base_url`.